# How to pass the binding context to custom handler call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm using Knockout custom handlers to update my objects like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.Tile = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var $element = $(element);

        var $parent = bindingContext.$parent || viewModel.$parent; // TODO: Clean up this mess

        /*
            Do lot of things using bindingContext.$parent, calculate elements dimension, populate fields etc.
        */
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        $(element).show();
    }
};

ko.bindingHandlers.TileColumn = {
    /*  another custom handler, we got a lot of those things  */
}
```

Now I implemented a Resize function and I can reuse all that weird logic in the custom handler to redraw/resize my elements.

```
var baseResize = this.Resize;
this.Resize = function () {
    baseResize.call(this);

    var tiles = this.Element.find('.tile');
    var tilesVM = this.DataSource.Items;

    for (var i = 0x0; i < tiles.length; i++) {

        tilesVM[i].$parent = this.ViewModel; // Clean up this mess too

        ko.applyBindingsToNode(tiles[i], null, tilesVM[i]);
    }
}
```

This works but feels like it's not the right way to do it. I'm struggling to refactor that handlers and get out of it the resize logic: not sure if this is the right way to do it.

While we wait for that refactoring I want a better way to call the `applyBindings` passing the correct `bindingContext`.

Note I did a very ugly thing here:

```
var $parent = bindingContext.$parent || viewModel.$parent; // TODO: Clean up this mess
```

And here:

```
tilesVM[i].$parent = this.ViewModel; // Clean up this mess too
```

Because the `bindingContext` parameter does not contain the parent view model when I explicit call the custom handler.

Of course that handler works just fine without that ugly messy line when the component loads and knockout is doing all the magic behind the curtain.

Comment: Not quite sure what your asking.  Can you generate a sample app ( jsFiddle, jsBin, etc ) to demonstrate.  Really need to see the relationship between all the custom bindings and the HTML

Comment: If you have inner HTML that you have to bind with a different context from your custom bindings you might want to look at this documentation http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-controlling-descendant-bindings.html

Comment: I guess when ko is handling the call from the html it is doing first the tile parent, second each tile and for last the tiles childs and it's setting the $parent property. My resize function is just calling applyBinding for each tile to apply all resize calculations embeded in the handler. I eventually ill refactor it, moving that calculations to a function outside the handler but I'm curious if there's a way to set the $parent property of the bindingContext at the time I'm calling the applyBinding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Robert, thanks for your time.
That documentation link does not helped since I got 3 levels: TileParent, Tile and TileChilds and I want to only call the Tile level and I cannot see a way to do it without applyBindingsToNode.

But that pointed me out to the binding documentation. After reading [this blog](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/knockout/bSKG240313-Understanding-Knockout-Binding-Context-Variable.html) and digging in the ko source code I realized one wonderfull thing: I can pass a ViewModel OR a BindingContext as parameter.

At first I was sad I cannot pass both at the same time but I see the VM is inside the BC $data.

Finally I found this usefull **ko.contextFor(element)**

```
            for (var i = 0x0; i < tiles.length; i++) {
            var bindingContext = ko.contextFor(tiles[i]);

            ko.applyBindingsToNode(tiles[i], null, bindingContext);
        }
```

and I also cleaned my handler callback

```
            var $parent = bindingContext.$parent;
```

Everything still working, but this time a bit more cleaner!

Comment: You should never have to use ko.contextFor, it indicates to me a code smell.  You can modify the binding context and control descendant bindings, maybe passing a composite object.   However I'm still unsure of the relationship between the custom bindings and your resize functions

Comment: The resize calculation depends on how much data are you trying to display inside the tile. Maybe that bad smell comes from the fact the custom binding handler callback was write in a way it ill require some time/effort to extract the resize logic from it. I'm pretty sure the rebinding *per si* is unnecessary. But there's not a valid scenario for ko.contextFor? Why?

Comment: Because any binding can create a new binding context tailoring the information to descendant DOM/bindings as required.  A binding should not need to reach up or around the current context to do its work.  The contextFor and dataFor is really designed for binding providers, not handlers.

Comment: I'm still interested in how the Resize function is invoked.  Is it wrapped by a dedicated binding handler, invoked from other custom handlers, or another mechanism completely

Comment: Neither. I have those bunch of nested widgets and the root is a singleton from the iWindows class. I declare a Resize function at the superclass of course and each widget implements it (or not) and containers calls its childs Resize events. At the frame widget a windows.Resize event calls for the root Resize function.